# How to make my table neater

Tags: tables, align

I have the following MWE:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|cc|}
    \hhline{|===|}
     \multirowthead{2}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Escape Probability }}\\
       & Analytical Result & Numerical Result\\
      \hline
      1 & $1- \sfrac{2}{\pi} \approx$ 0.36338 & 0.36337 \\
      2 & $2- \sfrac{4}{\pi} \approx$ 0.72676 & 0.72675 \\
      3 & $4- \sfrac{10}{\pi} \approx$ 0.81690 & 0.81690 \\
      4 & $14- \sfrac{124}{3\pi} \approx$ 0.84319 & 0.84319 \\
      5 & $66- \sfrac{614}{3\pi} \approx$ 0.85258 & 0.85258 \\
      $\infty$ & $1- \sfrac{2}{\pi} \approx$ 0.86338 & -- \\
      \hhline{|===|}
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which produces the following output:
[image]

I would like to neaten this up a bit. I would like to align my approximately equal signs and also what's on the left on my approximately equal signs (so 1-2/pi, 2-4/pi and so on). I also feel like the table is a little cramped, so I was wondering if it was possible to make it less so by adding whitespace above and below each cell?

Other suggestions to make my table neater are also appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add more columns in your tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,hhline,mathtools,xfrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r@{}l@{}lc|}
    \hhline{|=====|}
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{M}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Escape Probability }}\\
       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Analytical Result} & Numerical Result\\
      \hline
      1        & $1$  & ${}- \sfrac{2}{\pi}$    & ${} \approx 0.36338$ & $0.36337$ \\
      2        & $2$  & ${}- \sfrac{4}{\pi}$    & ${} \approx 0.72676$ & $0.72675$ \\
      3        & $4$  & ${}- \sfrac{10}{\pi}$   & ${} \approx 0.81690$ & $0.81690$ \\
      4        & $14$ & ${}- \sfrac{124}{3\pi}$ & ${} \approx 0.84319$ & $0.84319$ \\
      5        & $66$ & ${}- \sfrac{614}{3\pi}$ & ${} \approx 0.85258$ & $0.85258$ \\
      $\infty$ & $1$  & ${}- \sfrac{2}{\pi}$    & ${} \approx 0.86338$ & -- \\
      \hhline{|=====|}
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

The caption should not be part of the table. I'd avoid double rules and vertical rules. Also, “result” should not be duplicated.

I'd also avoid `\sfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} c >{$}r<{$} @{${}\approx{}$} c c @{}}
\toprule
M & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Results} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Analytical} & Numerical \\
\midrule
1        &  1-\frac{2}{\pi}    & 0.36338 & 0.36337 \\
\addlinespace
2        &  2-\frac{4}{\pi}    & 0.72676 & 0.72675 \\
\addlinespace
3        &  4-\frac{10}{\pi}   & 0.81690 & 0.81690 \\
\addlinespace
4        & 14-\frac{124}{3\pi} & 0.84319 & 0.84319 \\
\addlinespace
5        & 66-\frac{614}{3\pi} & 0.85258 & 0.85258 \\
\addlinespace
$\infty$ & 1-\frac{2}{\pi}     & 0.86338 & -- \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Escape probability}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly the [above answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654452/142180) by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), with tweaks mostly in mathematical representation. I do not know, if it is Ok in your area, but I tried to simplify the representation as much as I can, even at the expense of an additional factor of `\pi`. One could also use `siunitx`'s column type `S` for the numerical values, but it looked a bit ugly in this particular table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} c >{$}c<{$} c c c @{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{M} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Analytical results} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\times \pi$} &$\approx$& {approx.} & {Numerical} \\
\midrule
1        &  \pi-2    & & 0.36338 & 0.36337 \\
\addlinespace
2        &  2\pi-4    && 0.72676 & 0.72675 \\
\addlinespace
3        &  4\pi-10   && 0.81690 & 0.81690 \\
\addlinespace
4        & 14\pi - 124/3 && 0.84319 & 0.84319 \\
\addlinespace
5        & 66\pi - 614/3 && 0.85258 & 0.85258 \\
\addlinespace
$\infty$ & \pi-2     && 0.86338 & {--} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Escape probability}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot from the code above]

Comment: I have also noticed that the analytical result is `1 - 2/pi` for M=1 with approx. 0.36, and the analytical result `1 - 2/pi` for `M=\infty` with approx. 0.86. There is something wrong with the values there, so they are rather placeholders.

Comment: My values were supposed to be the actual values and not placeholders. Thanks for spotting that mistake, I completely missed that!